# Passing list of values to nested function in kdb

Tags: kdb

Function:

```
.terry.func:{
 tab:([]`a`b`c;b:1 2 3;c:`MSFT`GLE`APPLE);
 list:((`a,'1);(`b,'2));
 .terry.func2:{[t;x;y]select from t where a = x,b = y} [tab;;] each list;
 :.terry.func2
 }
```

The list I will actually extract from another table and will concatenate by ,'

However, I am not sure how to make this function work

Answer (score 3):

This may be what you are after:

```
.terry.func:{
 tab:([] a:`a`b`c;b:1 2 3;c:`MSFT`GLE`APPLE);
 list:((`a;1);(`b;2));
 {[t;x;y]select from t where a = x,b = y}[tab](.)/:list
  };
```

```
q)raze .terry.func[]
a b c   
--------
a 1 MSFT
b 2 GLE
```

- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/#apply-index
- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each-left-and-each-right

Comment: thanks. I saw some people would leave blank in the bracket [;;;] something like this, do you know how that works?

Comment: You can, but don't have to if you are projecting the first parmeter. For projecting other params you would need to position correctly .e.g `{[x;y;t] select from t where a = x,b = y }[;;tab]`

Comment: how to loop other params?

Answer (score 3):

Why not generate a table out of list?

```
.terry.func:{
 tab:([]a:`a`b`c;b:1 2 3;c:`MSFT`GLE`APPLE);
 list:`a`b!flip ((`a;1);(`b;2));
 select from tab where ([]a;b) in list
 }
```